# How to get request URL from a Node response object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm, https

When you use Node to make an http/https request (or with a wrapper such as [`simple-get`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-get)), you get back `err`, `response`, and `data` objects. Is there a way, within the callback, to get the original request URL, host, url, etc?

Example (using [`simple-get`'s concat](https://github.com/feross/simple-get#even-simpler-get-request)):

```js
const get = require('simple-get')

get.concat('http://example.com', function (err, res, data) {

  if (err) throw err

  console.log(res.statusCode) // 200
  console.log(res.headers) // {...}

  // i want "http://example.com" at this point
  console.log(res.uri) // undefined
  console.log(res.url) // undefined
  console.log(res.path) // undefined
  console.log(res.host) // undefined

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get some information from the underlying socket (as `simple-get` is just wrapper around the `http`-module) and from the `req`-object:

```
get.concat('https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/algorithms/', (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(res.socket.servername); // prints www.google.com
    console.log(res.req.path); // prints search/howsearchworks/algorithms
})
```